# Docker check if file exists in healthcheck

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How do I wait until a file is created in docker? I'm trying the code below, but it doesn't work. If I execute `bash -c [ -f /tmp/asdasdasd ]` separate from docker shell, it gives me the correct result.

**Dockerfiletest**:

```
FROM alpine:3.6
RUN apk update && apk add bash
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  testserv:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfiletest
    command:
       bash -c "rm /tmp/a && sleep 5 && touch /tmp/a && sleep 100"
    healthcheck:
      # I tried adding '&& exit 1',  '|| exit `' it doesn't work.
      test: bash -c [ -f /tmp/a ]
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 20
```

`docker-compose up` + wait 10s + `docker ps`:

```
: docker ps
STATUS    
Up About a minute (health: starting)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are missing quotes on the command to run. `bash -c` only accepts one parameter, not a list, so you need to quote the rest of that line to pass it as a single parameter:

```
bash -c "[ -f /tmp/a ]"
```

To see the results of your healthcheck, you can run:

```
docker inspect $container_id -f '{{ json .State.Health.Log }}' | jq .
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that besides missing quotes I also checked existence of socket via `-f` when I should do

```
bash -c '[ -S /tmp/uwsgi.sock ]'
```

Furthermore `interval: 5s` could be used to decrease default 5s interval.